# Copy various cells from one worksheet to another, and cells vary from week to week

Tags: vba, excel

My knowledge of using Macros extends to only recording what I require, however, using this method has limitations to what is copied and pasted.
[Proposed Future Work](https://i.stack.imgur.com/V1ySP.jpg) CopySheet
Each week as criteria are completed a TE and YR are assigned to a Capability...
The cells in Blue under CAP, DES, TE & YR then need copying and pasting (but only if a TE is assigned) to the next blank row (shaded areas in)...
[CPC](https://i.stack.imgur.com/Olc0i.jpg) PasteSheet
The code I have used is below:
Sub DataTransfer()
'
' DataTransfer Macro
' Transfer Proposed to CPC
'

```
Range("B9:L309").Select

ActiveWorkbook.Worksheets("Proposed Future Work").Sort.SortFields.Clear
ActiveWorkbook.Worksheets("Proposed Future Work").Sort.SortFields.Add Key:= _
    Range("K10:K309"), SortOn:=xlSortOnValues, Order:=xlAscending, DataOption _
    :=xlSortNormal
ActiveWorkbook.Worksheets("Proposed Future Work").Sort.SortFields.Add Key:= _
    Range("L10:L309"), SortOn:=xlSortOnValues, Order:=xlAscending, DataOption _
    :=xlSortNormal
ActiveWorkbook.Worksheets("Proposed Future Work").Sort.SortFields.Add Key:= _
    Range("B10:B309"), SortOn:=xlSortOnValues, Order:=xlAscending, DataOption _
    :=xlSortNormal
With ActiveWorkbook.Worksheets("Proposed Future Work").Sort
    .SetRange Range("B9:L309")
    .Header = xlYes
    .MatchCase = False
    .Orientation = xlTopToBottom
    .SortMethod = xlPinYin
    .Apply
End With
Rows("12:26").Select
Selection.EntireRow.Hidden = True
ActiveWindow.SmallScroll Down:=-18
Range("K10:L11").Select
Selection.Copy
Sheets("CPC-Salam").Select
Range("BD19").Select
Selection.PasteSpecial Paste:=xlPasteValues, Operation:=xlNone, SkipBlanks _
    :=False, Transpose:=False
Sheets("Proposed Future Work").Select
Range("B10:C11").Select
Application.CutCopyMode = False
Selection.Copy
Sheets("CPC-Salam").Select
Range("B19:C20").Select
Selection.PasteSpecial Paste:=xlPasteValues, Operation:=xlNone, SkipBlanks _
    :=False, Transpose:=False
Range("B9:BU308").Select
Application.CutCopyMode = False
ActiveWorkbook.Worksheets("CPC-Salam").Sort.SortFields.Clear
ActiveWorkbook.Worksheets("CPC-Salam").Sort.SortFields.Add Key:=Range( _
    "BD10:BD308"), SortOn:=xlSortOnValues, Order:=xlAscending, DataOption:= _
    xlSortNormal
ActiveWorkbook.Worksheets("CPC-Salam").Sort.SortFields.Add Key:=Range( _
    "BE10:BE308"), SortOn:=xlSortOnValues, Order:=xlAscending, DataOption:= _
    xlSortNormal
ActiveWorkbook.Worksheets("CPC-Salam").Sort.SortFields.Add Key:=Range( _
    "B10:B308"), SortOn:=xlSortOnValues, Order:=xlAscending, DataOption:= _
    xlSortNormal
With ActiveWorkbook.Worksheets("CPC-Salam").Sort
    .SetRange Range("B9:BU308")
    .Header = xlYes
    .MatchCase = False
    .Orientation = xlTopToBottom
    .SortMethod = xlPinYin
    .Apply
End With
Range("A10").Select
Sheets("Proposed Future Work").Select
Range("B10:L11").Select
Selection.ClearContents
Rows("11:27").Select
Selection.EntireRow.Hidden = False
Range("B9:L309").Select
ActiveWorkbook.Worksheets("Proposed Future Work").Sort.SortFields.Clear
ActiveWorkbook.Worksheets("Proposed Future Work").Sort.SortFields.Add Key:= _
    Range("K10:K309"), SortOn:=xlSortOnValues, Order:=xlAscending, DataOption _
    :=xlSortNormal
ActiveWorkbook.Worksheets("Proposed Future Work").Sort.SortFields.Add Key:= _
    Range("L10:L309"), SortOn:=xlSortOnValues, Order:=xlAscending, DataOption _
    :=xlSortNormal
ActiveWorkbook.Worksheets("Proposed Future Work").Sort.SortFields.Add Key:= _
    Range("B10:B309"), SortOn:=xlSortOnValues, Order:=xlAscending, DataOption _
    :=xlSortNormal
With ActiveWorkbook.Worksheets("Proposed Future Work").Sort
    .SetRange Range("B9:L309")
    .Header = xlYes
    .MatchCase = False
    .Orientation = xlTopToBottom
    .SortMethod = xlPinYin
    .Apply
End With
Rows("10:24").Select
Rows("10:24").EntireRow.AutoFit
Range("A10").Select
```

End Sub

Any suggestions would be welcome

Comment: I think you misunderstood this site, this is not a free coding services site ! you need to upload your code attempt, let us know where you are stuck / getting an error, and we will do our best to help you.

Comment: Apologies, thought I had pasted it in

Comment: The area that appears to be inconsistent is when I tried hiding rows with no TE / YR through to selecting the correct number of Cells with a TE/YR and pasting them in the correct empty cells on the CPC (pastesheet). Hope this clarifies my issue and that you are able to help.  Once again apologies for missing the code off.  Must have been having a senior moment

Answer (score 0):

After many trials, I found an answer to my vba issue, and decided to post it for any one else to utilise.

```
Sub DataTransfer()
'
' DataTransfer Macro
' Transfer Proposed to CPC
'

'Declare variables
    Dim sht1 As Worksheet
    Dim sht2 As Worksheet
'LRCT = Last Row in Copy Tab
    Dim LRCT As Integer
'FERPT = First Empty Row in Paste Tab
    Dim FERPT As Integer

'Set Variables
    Set sht1 = ThisWorkbook.Sheets("CPC")
    Set sht2 = ThisWorkbook.Sheets("Proposed Future Work")

'Stop the screen flickering
'    With Application
'        .ScreenUpdating = False
'    End With

'Apply sort to sheet2
    sht2.Range("B9:M309").Select
    ActiveWorkbook.Worksheets("Proposed Future Work").Sort.SortFields.Clear
    ActiveWorkbook.Worksheets("Proposed Future Work").Sort.SortFields.Add Key:= _
        Range("L10:L309"), SortOn:=xlSortOnValues, Order:=xlAscending, DataOption _
        :=xlSortNormal
    ActiveWorkbook.Worksheets("Proposed Future Work").Sort.SortFields.Add Key:= _
        Range("M10:M309"), SortOn:=xlSortOnValues, Order:=xlAscending, DataOption _
        :=xlSortNormal
    ActiveWorkbook.Worksheets("Proposed Future Work").Sort.SortFields.Add Key:= _
        Range("B10:B309"), SortOn:=xlSortOnValues, Order:=xlAscending, DataOption _
        :=xlSortNormal
    With ActiveWorkbook.Worksheets("Proposed Future Work").Sort
        .SetRange Range("B9:M309")
        .Header = xlYes
        .MatchCase = False
        .Orientation = xlTopToBottom
        .SortMethod = xlPinYin
        .Apply
    End With

'Find the last row with data in column K, sheet 2
    With sht2
    LRCT = .Cells(.Rows.Count, "L").End(xlUp).Row
    End With

'Find the first empty row in column BD, sheet 1
    With sht1
    FERPT = .Cells(.Rows.Count, "BD").End(xlUp).Row
    FERPT = FERPT + 1
    End With

'Copy data in sheet 2, starting from cell K10 to the last cell in column L
    sht2.Range("L10:M" & LRCT).Copy
'Paste data into sheet 1 column BD, starting from the first empty cell in column BD.
    sht1.Range(("BD" & FERPT)).PasteSpecial Paste:=xlPasteValues, Operation:=xlNone, SkipBlanks:=False, Transpose:=False

'Copy data in sheet 2, starting from cell B10 to the last cell in column L
    sht2.Range("B10:C" & LRCT).Copy
'Paste data into column B sheet 1, starting from the first empty cell in column BD.
    sht1.Range(("B" & FERPT)).PasteSpecial Paste:=xlPasteValues, Operation:=xlNone, SkipBlanks:=False, Transpose:=False

'Clear clipboard
    Application.CutCopyMode = False

'Remove copied data from sheet 2
    sht2.Range("L10:M" & LRCT).ClearContents
    sht2.Range("B10:C" & LRCT).ClearContents

'sort data in sheet1
    Sheets("CPC").Select
    Range("B9:BV309").Select
    ActiveWorkbook.Worksheets("CPC").Sort.SortFields.Clear
    ActiveWorkbook.Worksheets("CPC").Sort.SortFields.Add Key:=Range( _
        "BD10:BD309"), SortOn:=xlSortOnValues, Order:=xlAscending, DataOption:= _
        xlSortNormal
    ActiveWorkbook.Worksheets("CPC").Sort.SortFields.Add Key:=Range( _
        "BE10:BE309"), SortOn:=xlSortOnValues, Order:=xlAscending, DataOption:= _
        xlSortNormal
    ActiveWorkbook.Worksheets("CPC").Sort.SortFields.Add Key:=Range( _
        "B10:B309"), SortOn:=xlSortOnValues, Order:=xlAscending, DataOption:= _
        xlSortNormal
    With ActiveWorkbook.Worksheets("CPC").Sort
        .SetRange Range("B9:BV309")
        .Header = xlYes
        .MatchCase = False
        .Orientation = xlTopToBottom
        .SortMethod = xlPinYin
        .Apply
    End With

'sort data in sheet 2
    Sheets("Proposed Future Work").Select
    Range("B9:M309").Select
    ActiveWorkbook.Worksheets("Proposed Future Work").Sort.SortFields.Clear
    ActiveWorkbook.Worksheets("Proposed Future Work").Sort.SortFields.Add Key:= _
        Range("L10:L309"), SortOn:=xlSortOnValues, Order:=xlAscending, DataOption _
        :=xlSortNormal
    ActiveWorkbook.Worksheets("Proposed Future Work").Sort.SortFields.Add Key:= _
        Range("M10:M309"), SortOn:=xlSortOnValues, Order:=xlAscending, DataOption _
        :=xlSortNormal
    ActiveWorkbook.Worksheets("Proposed Future Work").Sort.SortFields.Add Key:= _
        Range("B10:B309"), SortOn:=xlSortOnValues, Order:=xlAscending, DataOption _
        :=xlSortNormal
    With ActiveWorkbook.Worksheets("Proposed Future Work").Sort
        .SetRange Range("B9:M309")
        .Header = xlYes
        .MatchCase = False
        .Orientation = xlTopToBottom
        .SortMethod = xlPinYin
        .Apply
    End With

'Update the screen
    With Application
        .ScreenUpdating = True
    End With

End Sub
```